# consume wcf service

Tags: sharepoint-server, wcf

I created application page in empty sharepoint page. Then i added service reference to my wcf service hosted outside sharepoint farm. It added reference successfully. But when i initialise

```
var mySer = new MyService();
```

i get error

```
Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MyService.IMyService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."
```

So then i added web reference instead of service reference. But when i access some of its methods i get error

```
SOAP header action was not found.
```

What is correct way to consume web service in sharepoint 2013 which are created outside farm.

When i consume same WCF service in normal asp.net application then it works. I add service reference in asp.net application and it works.

**Update1**
when i add webreference i dont see any app.config created. Is this might an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your bindings are correct in the SharePoint 2013 web config file and iis configurations, if your using http or net pipe bindings change accordingly in iis.

Comment: its not generating web.config file when i add web rererence

Comment: You can find web.config under virtual directories folder

Comment: So this web.config is not per project ?

Comment: For SharePoint projects it will be only one for web application

Comment: When i create empty sharepoint project then web.config is not added in solution? I mean i cant see it.. is it correct?

Comment: When u create empty sharepoint project, if u use farm solution, you will be giving the site collection for the Empty project, the site contains web config file which is located in Vitual directory("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories") with your application port number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23765/discussion-between-happy-and-shiva).

Comment: i created empty sharpoiint and then i specify this site http://doslaps104/  and select deploy as farm .. so where to local web.config

Comment: Go to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories" and select the port number which is user to create site, inside it you can find web.config

Comment: where to find this port no?

Comment: it is the number given while you are creating SharePoint web application

Comment: i cant see where.. i also checked all folders in inetpub and cant see any any web.config which is of todays date.. i have created fresh project 15 min back so i should see web.config of todays date but dont see anything of todays date

Comment: Is SharePoint web application is created by you... if yes what is the port number u have given there Go to inetpub-> wwwroot-> wss->VirtualDirectories->"{folder with port number}"->web.config

Comment: ok i got port number in centreal administration. Its 2000 but cant see any folder in inetpub folder . why?

Comment: Seems like there is problem with creation of web application, check it has created with exisitng IIS site instead of new one

Comment: i create new project and select sharepoint 2013 empty project and then select site doslaps104 for debugging and select deploy as form. thats it...

Comment: Ok...say some one has crearted SP web app - "doslaps104"- you need to get the web.config of this webapplication  and change that web.config

as it is said it is using 2000 port number, if you cannot find folder with 2000 in Virtual directiories there is a problem with web application, you have create a fresh web application and use it

Comment: yes i created fresh project so i dont know why no web.config.. hope u r talking about sharepoint and not asp.net web application

Comment: can you give me links on how to consume wcf services created outside sharepoint farm

Comment: Yes i am taking with respect to SharePoint only, what i am not understanding is when you create new web application from central administration why r u not able to create a folder . it seems some problem while creating web application. Web.config are created while creating web application it is nothing to do with projects.Hope you got my point

Comment: i am not creating web application using central administration. I use visual studio, select sharepoint 2013 empty project and deploy as farm solution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23767/discussion-on-answer-by-shiva-consume-wcf-service).